# Is it better to use call_user_func() in (e.g.) tt_content.php TCA and why? (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3, registration

I found in my ext_tables.php (build by Extension Builder) those rows:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die('Access denied.');

call_user_func(
    function()
    {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('rm_navigation', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Navigation');
    }
);
```

I migrate this for TYPO3 8 to Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php with those line:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die('Access denied.');

// Extensionregistration
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile('rm_navigation', 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'Navigation');
```

I read that's better to use the call_user_func function for this, but he/she doesn't wrote why.

So: is it better to use the call_user_func function?

And: why is this better?

Especially for TYPO3.

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you read that? What should be better that way?

Comment: I tried to find that posting, but I didn't. A programmer friend said that also, but he had no time at the moment to explain that. I searched stackoverflow, but didn't found something like that, so I created a new Question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is exactly one purpose for this construct: encapsulation.

Whenever you need a temporary variable in `ext_tables.php` or `ext_localconf.php` you risk leaking this variable into the same file of the next extension which is loaded after yours. A closure in PHP as a strict scope which prevents leaking variables into the closure as well as leaking variables to the surrounding code.

The reason for this is that all `ext_tables.php` and `ext_localconf.php` files are concatenated to a single file and stored in the cache. This is no problem for TCA and TCA overrides since these are stored as whole after building the whole array.

So in `ext_tables.php` or `ext_localconf.php` you should really use this construct.

Bonus: in PHP 7.x and newer this can be simplified:

```php
(function() {
    // ...
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. An example for understanding: I had an Exception, because I did **use ...ExtensionUtility** in two tt_content.php files, the Errormessage was something like **Is already loaded**... Can I prevent this behaviour too, and use "use" again, if I do the "encapsulation-trick" in tt_content.php ??

Comment: For now you should always use the FQCN everywhere to call static methods.

Comment: Do you know, can I also use that - or should I also use that in the TCA-Overrides for fe_users and fe_groups ? (Extension Builder didn't do a call_user_func wrap)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use this in TCA and TCA overrides since these files are not concatenated but included one by one after another and the result is put into the cache.